# How to divide all items in an array to a Double in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

So if I have

```
var passengersInDay: [Int] = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
var tripCost:Double
var tripDuration:Int
tripCostPerDay = tripCost / Double(tripDuration)
```

How to divide all elements of the `passengersInDay` array to the `tripCostPerDay` and put the result into a new array consisting of Doubles?

I tried using this operation

```
var singleDayCosts:[Double] = tripCostPerDay / passengersInDay
```

But swift keeps telling me that I can't divide an array that is expecting an int into a Double?, so I tried to call it `Double(passengersInDay)` but then a different error showed up.

Any thoughts?

Comment: i guess your problem is very easy but it's confusing see if below answer is what you mean

Comment: You should give up a compilable sample, with expected input/output code. Otherwise we'll get stuck in a fruitless loop of guessing what you want.

Comment: if you want to mutate the original array `tripCostPerDay = tripCostPerDay.indices.map { tripCostPerDay[$0] / passengersInDay[$0] }`

Comment: if you need in a new array of doubles `let doubles = tripCostPerDay.indices.map { Double(tripCostPerDay[$0]) / Double(passengersInDay[$0]) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
let singleDayCosts = passengersInDay.map { tripCostPerDay  / Double($0) }
```

Comment: @DobsTotev Would you care to share the error? We're not mind readers.

Comment: Ah sure, "[Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double']"

Comment: Now it worked, I had to switch it around: let singleDayCosts = passengersInDay.map {tripCostPerDay/Double($0)}